# how do I add a userprofile variable normally %userprofile%

Tags: java

I need to add a user profile variable in java, apparently %userprofile% does not work. when I try and enter this into the directory towards the bottom of the code it does not accept it. however I can echo my %userprofil% in command line

userprofile+"\Downloads\file.txt");

Comment: what you want to do exactly..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String System.getenv(String var)
```

so

```
String userprofile = System.getenv("USERPROFILE");
```

Then manipulate as desired (e.g. append the rest of your path...)

Alternatively, get the whole environment with  `Map<String,String> System.getenv()`

Comment: how exactly would I implement this?

Comment: got it! static String userprofile = System.getenv("USERPROFILE");

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking to get the current user's home directory. In Java you normally do it by calling `System.getProperty("user.home")`. But in Windows this might be assigned to %USERPROFILE% which makes things a bit complicated. See [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4787931). As a workaround, you might want to do what John3136 suggests: `System.getenv("USERPROFILE")` but it is not portable to other environments.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")`, not `System.getenv("user.home")`